# '-[AVPlayer superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21011ad0'

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer, unrecognized-selector

My app keeps crashing whenever I try to play a video, despite the fact that my AVPlayer instance is being retained.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"dd4dcafeea5111e1ad6712313b030e5d" withExtension:@"mp4"];

self.videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
[self addSubview:self.videoPlayer];
[((AVPlayer *)self.videoPlayer) play];
```

It's being assigned to this property:

```
@property (strong) id videoPlayer;
```

What's going on here? Am I not retaining something I should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AVPlayer` is not a subclass of `UIView`. You can't add a model object to your view hierarchy.